# Regular Expressions in Python - strange behaviour

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse the output of the `uptime` Unix command.
This are two different samples:

```
14:25  up 1 day,  1:24, 2 users, load averages: 0,56 0,48 0,47
14:25  up 1:24, 2 users, load averages: 0,56 0,48 0,47
```

(The language I'm using is Python)

So, say that the two samples above are saved into the variables `s1` and `s2`.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
>>> RE = r'''
    ((\d) \s day)?        # this should match "n day" if it's there 
    .*?                   # this should match everything until the next regex
    \s(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) # this should match a space followed by "hh:mm"
'''

>>> print re.match(RE, s1, re.VERBOSE).groups()
(None, None, '1', '24')
>>> print re.match(RE, s2, re.VERBOSE).groups()
(None, None, '1', '24')
```

The second part of the regex, the one that grabs the hours-minutes of the uptime, works perfectly. But why does the first part of the tuple is always `None`? What am I missing? Is it a *greedy* vs *non-greedy* problem?

Comment: Your regex has three spaces between n and day. Furthermore, since you are using match, it would find it only at the start of the string.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: This is a `re.VERBOSE` pattern; whitespace is ignored.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Python does not count hardcoded spaces as spaces with `re.VERBOSE`, you have to escape them. It doesn't work, even when cutting off the spaces.

Comment: @MartijnPieters right, thanks for the correction. I think my second observation still stands

Comment: Neither should the second observations be true. It doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Using seach actually gives the same results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, exactly.

Comment: @Awalias nope, now it has become a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to move the `.*?` *into* the optional day group and use `.search()`:

```
RE = r'''
    (?:(\d) \s day.*?)?   # this should match "n day" if it's there
    \s(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) # this should match a space followed by "hh:mm"
'''
```

Demo:

```
>>> RE = r'''
...     (?:(\d) \s day.*?)?        # this should match "n day" if it's there
...     \s(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}) # this should match a space followed by "hh:mm"
... '''
>>> print re.search(RE, s1, re.VERBOSE).groups()
('1', '1', '24')
>>> print re.search(RE, s2, re.VERBOSE).groups()
(None, '1', '24')
```

The pattern anchors on the `:`, then backtracks. The `.*?` then matches the whole text preceding the time signature, which satisfies the pattern.

By moving the `.*?` part *into* the optional `day` group (made non-capturing in my version) you guarantee that it won't backtrack past the `day` literal text.

Comment: `search` behaves exactly like `match` here.

Comment: Ok, this works. Did you copy&pasted the output of your console or did you wrote it? Because the tuple should be four elements long.

Comment: @whatyouhide: No, I adjusted the pattern to not capture the `day` part. No point in returning literal text with the `.*?` trail added. It would only *repeat* what you already have, the `1` for `1 day` in the next group.

Comment: Oh yes, ok then the `?` at the beginning is for that I guess. I still have to get confident with regexes.

Comment: @whatyouhide: indeed, `(?:...)` creates a *non-capturing* group; a group just for logical purposes instead of for returning captured information.

Answer (score 0):

match starts at the begining of string, add .*? at the begining

```
In [37]: RE=r'.*?((\d) \s day) .*?  \s(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})'

In [38]: print re.match(RE, s1, re.VERBOSE).groups()
('1 day', '1', '1', '24')
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than read from the command line an alternative approach would be to read directly from `/proc/uptime`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import timedelta

with open('/proc/uptime', 'r') as f:
    uptime_seconds = float(f.readline().split()[0])
    uptime_string = str(timedelta(seconds = uptime_seconds))

print(uptime_string)
```

output:

```
35 days, 23:06:35.530000
```

this is now much easier to parse with tokenise or split built-ins

Comment: Oh, ok then. Thank you. My question was not about that, it was about regexes only, but sure I'm gonna give this a try :).